# Google Cloud Load Balancer with wildcard

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-app-engine, google-cloud-network-load-balancer

For example, there are the following applications deployed as App Engine and Cloud Run services.

A) `app-1-api` as Cloud Run service

B) `app-2-api` as App Engine service

C) `app-1-frontend` a NextJS app as Cloud Run service

D) `app-2-frontend` a static website hosted as Cloud Run service

I found an [article](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless) that describes how serverless NEGs with Google Cloud Balancer can glue all these services together behind a single domain. I would like to achieve the following routing:

1. A request to `api.example.com` should hit service `A`
2. A request to `reporting-api.example.com` should hit service `B`
3. A request to `reporting.example.com` should hit service `D`
4. If a request matches the path `*.example.com` and none of the paths 1 - 3, then the request should hit service `C`.

I haven't found anything in regards to the wildcard subdomain in 4. Is all this possible? If not, what GCP alternatives are there?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[The name of that you are looking for is **URL Map.**](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map)

URL maps are used with the following Google Cloud products:

- External HTTP(S) Load Balancing (global, regional, and classic modes)
- Internal HTTP(S) Load Balancing
- Traffic Director

The hostname must be a fully qualified domain name (FQDN). The hostname can't be an IPv4 or IPv6 address. For example:

Works: example.com

Works: web.example.com

Works: *.example.com

Doesn't work: 35.244.221.250

Check the reference [about how to Add a host rule](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map#add_a_host_rule)

Before to start with the URL map, please familiarize yourself with [URL map concepts.](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts), such as:

1. How URL maps work
2. Naming
3. URL map components
4. URL redirects

For example, with an external HTTP(S) load balancer, you can use a single URL map to route requests to different destinations based on the rules configured in the URL map:

Requests for https://example.com/video go to one backend service.

Requests for https://example.com/audio go to a different backend service.

Requests for https://example.com/images go to a Cloud Storage backend bucket.

Requests for any other host and path combination go to a default backend service.

Comment: How would you redirect a subdomain to a bucket subfolder, if you have more than 3 subdomains. Currently, the quota limit for Backend buckets is 3. Initially, I wanted to create a separate Backend bucket for each subdomain, which would resolve this URL redirect issue.